# Not Available (como colocar informação nessa posiçao)

Tags: r

Preciso de ajuda. Tenho um dataframe no R com algumas colunas *NA* (sei que é coluna sem informação) e gostaria de adicionar informação nessa posição, mas não tenho ideia de como fazer isso. Preciso de ajuda. Obrigada!!

Comment: Bianca, a pergunta está muito genérica. Que tipo de informação deve substituir o `NA`? É algo pré-definido por ti? Ou tu não sabe que informação deve ser adicionada, desejando realizar uma imputação de dados através de algum critério matemático?

Answer (score 1):

A melhor forma de dar um exemplo de dados, neste caso uma `data.frame` é utilizar o comando `dput`:

```
dput(dat)  # postar o output disto
```

Vamos primeiro produzir uma `data.frame` exemplo.

```
set.seed(2174)
dat <- data.frame(X <- rnorm(10),
            A = sample(letters[1:4], 10, TRUE),
            stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
dat$X[c(2,4,7)] <- NA
```

Agora temos tudo o que é preciso. Suponhamos que temos um `valor` para os `NA`.

```
inx <- is.na(dat$X)
dat$X[inx] <- valor  # 'valor' deve ser numérico
```

É só isso. Simples, não?

Answer (score 1):

Olá @Bianca, tente a função coalesce do pacote dplyr. Ela substitui todos os NAs pelo valor indicado, no exemplo abaixo é zero:

```
x <- sample(c(1:5, NA, NA, NA))
dplyr::coalesce(x, 0L)
```